# iOS - take screenshot of springboard(home screen) programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, screenshot, springboard

is it possible to take screenshot of home screen of iPhone before start my application in iOS.

I had tried google and stack overflow but it only allow to take screenshot of any screen of my application.

Look at the following screen which I want to make for my application background.

[image]

Any suggestion will appreciated.

Comment: Why you need the iPhone home screen screenshot in your app ?

Comment: client want his app with blury-background as i given screenshot.so like user can see his/her home screen as well with blurry while using application.

Answer (score 0):

Taking screenshots outside your sandbox is not possible unless you have Jailbreak since that would be huge privacy issue. Sorry to be bearer of the bad news.

One and probably only option is to ask user to choose background himself. Second option is to build [Today extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html), which is then shown in your notification center - then you would have background you desire.